Flutter : Close PopUpMenu using PopUpMenuButtonState
I want to close the menu after opening it with a click :
So I want to use the state of the PopupMenuButton to close it.
I tried :
_popUpKey.currentState?.dispose();

  final _popUpKey = GlobalKey();

                      PopupMenuButton<int>(
                        key: _popUpKey,
                        onSelected: (value) {
                          // Handle the selected value
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context) => [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Text('Option 1'),
                          ),
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            value: 2,
                            child: Text('Option 2'),
                          ),
                        ],


If you use SetState inside the onSelected help you?
      onSelected: (SampleItem item) {
        setState(() {
          selectedItem = item;
        });
      },

Need to be StateFull.
More here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html
